# How to insert formated sql getdate() into table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, ado.net

i know that how to format SQL getdate() function like these:-

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 101) – mm/dd/yyyy - 10/02/2008                   
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 102) – yyyy.mm.dd – 2008.10.02           
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 103) – dd/mm/yyyy
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 104) – dd.mm.yyyy
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 105) – dd-mm-yyyy
```

My question is that how to insert these formated string in the particular table.
I also tried like this:-

```
insert into messagebox values('abcd','abcd',SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 101) )
```

but i am getting error. How to accomplish this task? 
thank you

Comment: What error do you get? What is your `messagebox` table structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try and remove the select

```
insert into messagebox values('abcd','abcd',convert(varchar, getdate(), 101) )
```

Comment: +1 for noticing it... i noticed after read your answer .. i just ignores tht select whil reading question :)